# How to fix 'java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect'

Tags: java

I'm trying to send an email through my website (JSF website), which is deployed on an apache server I keep getting 'Connection Refused: Connect', but if I run the code from a java application directly from NetBeans the code works perfectly.
And sorry if I made some errors in the post, you could say its my first time posting. :)

```
    public void sendReplicationCheckResult() {
    String to = "JcbSupportingSystem@jcbank.com.jo";

    // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
    String from = "Palestine.IT@jcbank.com.jo";

    // Assuming you are sending email from localhost
    String host = "192.168.52.95";

    // Get system properties
    Properties properties = System.getProperties();

    // Setup mail server
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "25");

    // Get the default Session object.
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

    try {
        // Create a default MimeMessage object.
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

        // Set From: header field of the header.
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

        // Set To: header field of the header.
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));

        // Set Subject: header field
        message.setSubject("Replication Check Results");

        // Create the message part 
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setContent(message, "text/html");

        // Create a multipart message
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        // Set text message part
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        // Part two is attachment
        messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        String filename = "C:\\Temp\\ReplicationCheck.pdf";
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        // Send the complete message parts
        message.setContent(multipart);

        // Send message
        SMTPTransport t = (SMTPTransport) session.getTransport("smtp");

        // connect
        t.connect(new Socket(host, 25));

        // send
        t.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());

        System.out.println("Response: " + t.toString());

        t.close();
        Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get("C:\\Temp\\ReplicationCheck.pdf"));
    } catch (MessagingException mex) {
        mex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SendEmail.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Start the server before the client, or get the IP:port right in the client.

Comment: the server is running, and the ip:port are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem with the following code.
My friend told me that java requires a valid username and password to connect to smtp server after its deployed on apache, so I added them but my problem was solved after I used sslsocket to connect not normal socket. (t.connect(new Socket(host, 25));) //old way
//the new code use (t.connect(new SSLSocket(SMTP_SERVER, 25)).

```
private static final String SMTP_SERVER = "smtp server";
private static final String USERNAME = "username";
private static final String PASSWORD = "password";

private static final String EMAIL_FROM = "email from";
private static final String EMAIL_TO = "email to";
private static final String EMAIL_TO_CC = "cc";

private static final String EMAIL_SUBJECT = "Subject";

public void sendReplicationCheckResult() {

    // Get system properties
    Properties properties = System.getProperties();

    // Setup mail server
    properties.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", SMTP_SERVER);
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "25");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");

    // Get the default Session object.
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

    try {
        // Create a default MimeMessage object.
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

        // Set From: header field of the header.
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(EMAIL_FROM));

        // Set To: header field of the header.
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(EMAIL_TO));

        // Set Subject: header field
        message.setSubject(EMAIL_SUBJECT);

        // Create the message part 
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

        // Fill the message
//            messageBodyPart.setText("This is message body");
        // Create a multipart message
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        // Set text message part
 //multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        // Part two is attachment
        messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        String filename = "File Path";
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName("File Name");
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        // Send the complete message parts
        message.setContent(multipart);

        // Send message
        SMTPTransport t = (SMTPTransport) session.getTransport("smtp");

        // connect
        t.connect(new SSLSocket(SMTP_SERVER, 25) {
            @Override
            public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public String[] getEnabledCipherSuites() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public void setEnabledCipherSuites(String[] strings) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public String[] getSupportedProtocols() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public String[] getEnabledProtocols() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public void setEnabledProtocols(String[] strings) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public SSLSession getSession() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public void addHandshakeCompletedListener(HandshakeCompletedListener hl) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public void removeHandshakeCompletedListener(HandshakeCompletedListener hl) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public void startHandshake() throws IOException {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public void setUseClientMode(boolean bln) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public boolean getUseClientMode() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public void setNeedClientAuth(boolean bln) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public boolean getNeedClientAuth() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public void setWantClientAuth(boolean bln) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public boolean getWantClientAuth() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public void setEnableSessionCreation(boolean bln) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public boolean getEnableSessionCreation() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }
        });
        // send
        t.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());

        System.out.println("Response: " + t.toString());

        t.close();
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(null, "Email was sent Successfully"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SendEmail.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(null, ex.getLocalizedMessage()));
    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(null, ex.getLocalizedMessage()));
        Logger.getLogger(SendEmail.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`192.168.52.95` is a [LAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_area_network) address. While in your development environment it may have a mail server waiting for things, in your server environment there is nothing at `192.168.52.95`.

You might want to read the host from a property file, that way you can use different hosts in different environments.

Comment: Yes this is the ip of the exchange server, which all emails are sent through it in my work place.

Comment: Are both servers on the same network? Find your network guy and tell him your problem, he'll sort you out.

Comment: I'm not sure but i think they are not, but i can ping the exchange server and it works, and if i run the code from a java project without deploying it on tomcat server it works fine, i'm facing this problem only when i try to run the code from apache.

Comment: If you can connect to host / port 25 **from** the server where tomcat is running, then you can access the mail server. Otherwise you can't. You said you don't think they're on the same network, but they need to be for it to work.

Comment: Ok thanks for you answer, i'll try connection to the host/port 25 to see if it works,     
do you think it's a problem on the apache side like configuration?

Comment: So I tried connecting using telnet host/port 25 and it connected successfully from the windows server where the apache is installed, but when I try to end the email through the website that is deployed on the apache I get the error 'java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect'

Comment: Then there's some other issue. Connection refused means almost always that there's nothing listening (although there may be another reason to drop a connection, such as too many people trying to connect). But then you shouldn't be able to connect with telnet either. On the other hand it should throw a different kind of exception if there are issues with for example username or password.

Comment: As a friend suggested, java needs a valid username and password to connect to smtp server when deployed to apache server. thanks again for your help.